# Initialize Angular $scope on initial load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to init the user session with some data. On loading the main outer controller (I have a "global" controller that is run for the entire app and individual controllers for each state/route) I currently check if the local session data is empty and, if so, fetch from server and return a promise.

The issue that I have is that I use directives which need this session data. Currently they  run before the scope is populated. I need a solution that does not involve modifying all the directives to use promises/callbacks/etc.

On researching this I found many requests but no viable solutions.  I am using UI router and looked at the grandfather state idea but that just seems to act as a master resolve that still needs to be addressed in each controller.

I have also looked at manually bootstrapping but I need to populate the scope and I don't see how to do that from angular.element.

I should add that this needs to a pause the Angular process until loading. I see suggestions for global configuration but not sure how do pause besides deferring bootstrapping.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your provider which will perform you some functionality.
You can take a look [here - Documentation for providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) how to do it. From the link you can see:
`You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts.`

By the way, if you want to access scope from angular.element = you can use:
`angular.element(<yourElement>).scope()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you do your work in main module's .run method. and set whatever you want at $rootScope.

That way it will be visible everywhere.

[Angular Modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Answer (score 0):

You can use value receipe, [ngtutorial.com/learn/value](http://ngtutorial.com/learn/value)